# Thymeleaf render on fragments

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm having a troublesome with thymeleaf, accordingly to this documentation [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#rendering-template-fragments) I'm able to render just a part of  my html page, using a fragment, I tried to use it with the controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/showContentPart")
public String showContentPart() {
...
return "index :: content";
}
```

and in HTML

```
<div id="content">
  Only this will be rendered!!
</div>
```

However what I want is that a user click on a link on a nav bar and the div should render and the layout should stay static, in other words.. I want to maintain my layout and change the div content, however when I click for the link I get just get the content without my layout, I'm doing somehting wrong?

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't really support this kind of automatic refresh.  It's a server side rendering technology.  You're going to have to either write your own javascript to do this, or use another framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the name of your fragment as a model attribute to replace the content in your layout:

```
@RequestMapping("/showContentPart")
public String showContentPart(Model model) {
    model.setAttribute("contentName", "content")
    return "layoutPage";
}
```

In layout page, you can include your content like this:

```
<div id="layout">
    <div th:include="index :: ${contentName}"></div>
</div>
```

`showContentPart` method will return your layout page, but with desired content. If you want to include some other content, you just make the similar method but with different value of "contentName" model attribute.

Comment: Sorry, still not working, however now returns my layout the fragment inside div is still missing...